# Using local memory argument in OpenCL kernel called from OpenCL R interface

Tags: r, kernel, opencl

I'm using the [OpenCL interface in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/OpenCL/index.html) , for calling an OpenCL-kernel from R code. I would like to use local memory arguments in my OpenCL kernel definition, for example:

```
__kernel void testKernel(__global numeric* output, const unsigned int count, __local numeric* tmp, ) { // kernel code .... }
```

If I call the kernel from R with the OpenCL R-Interface:

```
res = as.numeric(oclRun(kernel = k.test, size   = Size,                                   as.clBuffer(VectorizedInput, Context)))
```

The OpenCL R-Interface expects a value for the __local memory argument.

As far as I know it is needed to set in clSetKernelArg , the argValue argument to NULL to use the __local memory object in as argument in the OpenCL kernel., if I would call the kernel myself. But I'm not sure if this is possible with the OpenCL R-Interface or if their is a way around it.
I would appreciate if someone has some experience in using __local memory objects in the kernel arguments, while calling it with the OpenCL R-Interface and if it is possible in any way.

I tried to create buffer objects of the same type, the __local memory is, but this those not work, neither NULL values or no argument values at all.

Comment: I use OpenCL with c not R, but you're not allowed to use local variables as kernel arguments in c. I suspect it's the same in R.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already suspected that it may be not possible.

Comment: Local memory isn't persistent between kernel calls so you have to allocate it and initialise it in the kernel so why would you even want to use it as a kernel argument? You can allocate it in the kernel and then initialise it from a global variable or argument.

Comment: I wanted to use it for storing intermediate data inside one kernel, since I need something to save intermediate calculations to calculate my output and optimally with no necessity to copy anything from the host memory for this. At least according to the OpenCL-R-Interface documentation, all global memory inputs except the output argument, are read only and can not really used for this purpose.

Comment: Since I have an upperbound known for the space I need in the time the kernel is called I could use it in the kernel arguments, but can not hardcode the size inside the kernel, since the upperbound is not known beforehand. At the moment the only solution I have found is to make the output argument big enough, to use it also to store the intermediate data calculations and later cut them from the results in R.

Comment: Can't you just create a global buffer big enough to hold the data you need between kernel calls, which you only need to do once if you know at runtime how big it needs to be?

Comment: Yes, I will have to do it that way and make the global output memory argument big enough to hold my intermediate calculations and then cut them away in R, since all other global memory arguments, when called with the OpenCL R-Interface are read only. But at least it should be a workable get around.